# Looping function on my int isMember()

Tags: c, arrays, function

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isMember();
float calculatePrice(int,int,int);
void printPlayer();
char name[4][100];
char name1[100];
int numofplayer, i, numofbook;
int member;
float game, discount, gst, subtotal, total;

int main()
{
    i=0;

    printf ("Your name: ");
    gets (name1);

    printf ("No of player: ");
    scanf ("%d",&numofplayer);

    while (i<numofplayer)
    {
        printf ("Enter Player %d: ",i+1);
        scanf ("%s",name[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf ("How many game do you want to book?: ");
    scanf ("%d",&numofbook);

    isMember();

    calculatePrice(isMember(),numofbook,numofplayer);

    printf ("=======================\n");

    printf ("Your booking detail.\n");

    printf ("Your name is: %s",name1);
    printf ("\nNo of player: %d",numofplayer);
    printf ("\nList of player ");

    printPlayer();

    printf ("\nNo of game: %d",numofbook);

    if (isMember()==1)
    {
        printf ("Status member: member \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Status member: not a member \n");
    }

    printf ("Total price is (including GST): %.2f",calculatePrice(isMember(),numofbook,numofplayer));

    return 0;
}


int isMember()
{
    printf ("Are you a member of this club?(1-yes or 0=no): ");
    scanf ("%d",&member);

    return member;
}

float calculatePrice(int a, int b, int c)
{

    game=25;
    subtotal=game*c;
    subtotal=subtotal*b;

    if (a==1)
    {
        discount=subtotal*0.1;
        subtotal=subtotal-discount;
    }

    gst=0.06*subtotal;
    total=subtotal-gst;

    return total;
    }

    void printPlayer()
    {
    int i;
    i=0;


    while (i<numofplayer)
    {
        printf ("%d) ",i+1);
        printf ("%s \n",name[i]);
        i++;
    }


}
```

Why did it loop at my `isMember()`?

It keeps looping over and over then it stops, and the other function I am not even confident if it runs correctly.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't loop.
Instead of keeping the returned value from `isMember()`, you called it over and over again.
You should define a new variable and save the result in it.

```
res = isMember();
```

and use `res` anywhere you called `isMember()`.